Estimating regression coefficients where the Fisher Information is $0$?
I have a basic linear mixed-effect model:
$$ y_{ij} = X_{ij}\beta + Z_{ij}b_i + \epsilon_{ij} $$
Where:

$y_{ij}$ is the j-th observation for the i-th group

$X_{ij}$ is the fixed effects design matrix

$\beta$ is the fixed effects parameter vector

$Z_{ij}$ is the random effects design matrix

$b_i$ is the random effects vector for the i-th group

$\epsilon_{ij}$ is the error term

$b_i \sim N(0, \Sigma) $

$\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $


The log-likelihood function for this model is:
$$ y_i \sim N(X_i\beta, V_i) $$
$$ f(y) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}|V|^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^T V^{-1}(y-\mu)\right) $$
$$ f(y_i) = (2\pi)^{-n_i/2}|V_i|^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(y_i-X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1}(y_i-X_i\beta)\right) $$
$$ \log f(y_i) = -\frac{n_i}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\log|V_i| - \frac{1}{2}(y_i-X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1}(y_i-X_i\beta) $$
$$ l(\beta, \Sigma, \sigma^2) = \sum_{i=1}^m \log f(y_i) $$
$$ l(\beta, \Sigma, \sigma^2) = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ n_i \log(2\pi) + \log|V_i| + (y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta) \right] $$
On my way to calculate the Fisher Information (i.e. for variance estimation), I started to take the second derivatives/Hessian with respect to the variance components $\theta$:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log|V| = \text{tr}(V^{-1}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta})$
$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (V^{-1}) = -V^{-1}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}V^{-1}$

$$ \frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \text{tr}(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}) - (y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta) \right] $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \text{tr}(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}) = \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}\right) $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left[(y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta)\right] = -(y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta) $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta^2} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}\right) - (y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta) \right] $$
Taking the expectation with respect to $y$ (note: $E[(y_i - X_i\beta)(y_i - X_i\beta)^T] = V_i$):
$$ \begin{align*}
E\left[-\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta^2}\right] &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}\right) - E\left[(y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta)\right] \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}\right) - \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}V_i\right) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m \left[ \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}\right) - \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta}\right) \right] \\
&= 0
\end{align*} $$
However, it seems that this is $0$!
It seems like the Fisher method can not be used in this problem. In situations like this, does Iterative Reweighted Least Squares (IRLS) become more favorable for parameter estimation? Or is my math incorrect?


Note: $(y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta)$ is a scalar (1×1 matrix)

Any scalar, it equals its trace. So:
$$ (y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta) = \text{tr}\left((y_i - X_i\beta)^T V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta)\right) $$

You have missed a factor of two in the computation of the second-order derivative of the inverse matrix.
For $V$ symmetric, one has that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 V^{-1}}{\partial x_j\partial x_k} &= V(x)^{-1}\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_j}V(x)^{-1}\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_k}V(x)^{-1}\\
&\quad + V(x)^{-1}\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_k}V(x)^{-1}\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_j}V(x)^{-1}\\
&= \boldsymbol{2}V(x)^{-1}\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_j}V(x)^{-1}\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_k}V(x)^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial\theta_j\partial\theta_k} &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m  \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_j}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_k}\right)\\
&\quad -\frac{\boldsymbol{2}}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m (y_i - X_i\beta)^\top V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_j} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_k} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta).
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, because:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{E}\left[(y_i - X_i\beta)^\top V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_j} V_i^{-1} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_k} V_i^{-1} (y_i - X_i\beta)\right]\\
&\quad = \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_j}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_k}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
One gets:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial\theta_j\partial\theta_k}\right] &= -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^m  \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_j}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_k}\right)\\
&\quad + \boldsymbol{1}\sum_{i=1}^m  \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_j}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m  \text{tr}\left(V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_j}V_i^{-1}\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial \theta_k}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, the last expression gives you the block of the Fisher/expected information matrix concerning the variance components. It must not be zero.
Reference
Stroup (2012). Generalized Linear Mixed Models: Modern Concepts, Methods and Applications. Chapman & Hall/CRC, New York.
